# xUnit for UWP apps (Windows 10)

Tags: uwp, xunit.net

I have to write unit tests for a UWP app, i want to use xUnit.
I followed this link : https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-uwp.html

But no tests are discovered.

Comment: did you build the unit tests project?  tests usually are not discovered until built

Comment: I did build them , builds successfully but doesnt show any tests

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to set correct processor architecture for tests in Visual Studio menu:
Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture.
After this you need to rebuild unit test project.